# strange button outline color when having colored background

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, frontend, tailwind-css

When i use background color the button shows a strange outline color
[as you can notice the left darkness line and right white line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s3fy.png)

compared to when using a white background the outline disappear
[no outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSPDw.png)

this is my code

```
<button type="submit" className="bg-[#fa5252] rounded py-[1.2rem] px-[2.4rem]">Add</button>

body {
    background-color: #1864ab;
}
```

i tried border: none and outline: none

Comment: HI, I don't see what border you're referring to. I wonder if it could simply be an optical effect du to the colors you use ("red" and "blue" next to each are known to induce this kind of effect: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromostereopsis) ?

Comment: Hello, Indeed yes it was an optical effect, thanks for the answer.